# How can I center a right-aligned DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has text that is right aligned.  I want to then center that div within its parent.

The code below only applies the right-alignment.

CSS

```
.outerDiv {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.innerDiv {
    text-align: right;
    width: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
        10<br/>
        <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
            + 2
        </span><br />
        12
    </div>
</div>
```

I know this can be done with using `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` in the outer div, but that requires that you set the inner div's width, which I don't know ahead of time.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're setting `text-align: center` on the parent element, you could simply set the `display` of the inner element to `inline-block`. In doing so, the inner element will be centered horizontally due to the fact that it has a ["shrink-to-fit" width](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) based on the width of its contents:

```css
.outerDiv {
  text-align: center;
}
.innerDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
.innerDiv span {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    10<span>+ 2</span>12
  </div>
</div>
```

I also removed the `<br />` elements, and changed the `display` of the `span` element to `block`. You could also just replace it with a `p` element (since it's already block-level by default).

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `<center>` html tag:

```
<center>
    <div class="outerDiv">
        <div class="innerDiv">
            10<br/>
            <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                + 2
            </span><br />
            12
        </div>
   </div>
</center>
```

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Didn't know, Thank you :) !